# How to get HTTP status code in GraphQL apollo-android client

Tags: android, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-android

I am using apollo client https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android to query Graphql API. In Graphql Server, we are returning with HTTPS status

```
return Response.status( Status.BAD_REQUEST ).entity( exception.getMessage() ).build();
```

How can I get HTTPS status code in response at client side?

Client code

```
ApolloCall<T> apolloCall = apolloClient.query( query );
Response<T> response = Rx2Apollo.from( apolloCall ).onErrorReturn( throwable -> null ).blockingFirst();
```

I majorly want to know whether the error is client exception or server exceeption.

Comment: response contains `data` and `errors` (if error exists) props

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/blob/96d53ba7ec479e4e2c05dcc456e74031985f0bb6/apollo-api/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/apollographql/apollo/api/Error.kt 

@xadm Error does not contain HTTPS status.

Comment: @xadm it still gives you Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}, but no http status. Status can be helpful to know it sever error or client error.

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues?q=is%3Aissue+onHttpError+

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `.onErrorReturn( throwable -> null )` part and the HTTP error will be returned in `onError` as a `ApolloHttpException` on which you can call `.code()` to get the HTTP code.